# How to set custom marker icons from GeoJSON data

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I receive a response from the server in GeoJSON format and add this all to the map

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/coupling/select/',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            sw_lat: southWest.lat,
            sw_lon: southWest.lng,
            ne_lat: northEast.lat,
            ne_lon: northEast.lng
        },
        success: function (data) {
            L.geoJSON(data, {
                icon: leafletIcon, 
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map)
        },
        complete: function () {
            loader_countdown_dec('coupling');
        }
    });
```

Code function leafletIcon:

```
function leafletIcon(feature){
    if(feature.properties.obj == 1){
        return L.icon({iconUrl: 'images/cable.png'});
    }
    else if(feature.properties.obj == 2){
        return L.icon({iconUrl: 'images/boxpon.png'});
    }
    else if(feature.properties.obj == 3){
        return L.icon({iconUrl: 'images/coupling.png'});
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to change the icon depending on the object number. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the icon directly to the marker:

```
 L.geoJSON(data, {
                pointToLayer: pointToLayer, 
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map)

function pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: leafletIcon(feature)});
}
```